# Core Data adding a new NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have my Core Data set up as such:

`SALES_REP` <--->> `CUSTOMER` <---->> `PURCHASE_AGREEMENT` <<------->> `PRODUCTS`

In the app, the sales rep can change the attributes of the `PRODUCTS` entity and this triggers changes to the `PURCHASE_AGREEMENT`. When they are finished editing the working `PA`, they can either submit via a web service to our CRM (SAP) or save their work locally.

I understand (at least I think I do : D) how to create a new `NSManagedObject` and add values to it's attributes:

```
NSManagedObject* newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PA" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];

//get the entity descriptions for PA, Customer, PA_Products and Sales_Rep
NSEntityDescription* PAEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PA" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
NSDictionary* dictPAAttributes = [PAEntity attributesByName];
NSArray* arrPAAttributeNames = [dictPAAttributes allKeys];

for(NSString* strThisAttribute in arrPAAttributeNames) {
    [newManagedObject setValue:[self.workingPA valueForKey:strThisAttribute] forKey:strThisAttribute];
}
```

How would I go about adding the relationships? Do I have to fetch the newly created `PA` entity and then pull for the products, pull the `NSSet` of products from the workingPA and then add them to the new PA? And would the process be similar for the `CUSTOMER` and `SALES_REP` entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the first question is why bother having a workingPA at all, why not just let them edit the newManagedObject directly. then you just need to call `[moc save]`.

But to create the relationships you need to create new ones because the old ones are between the workingPA object and the other objects.

Do yourself a favour and start by [creating `NSManagedObject` subclasses](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_mo_class.html) like

```
PurchaseAgreement 
Customer
Product
```

Then assuming you have them you may also need to create another object called PAItem to keep track of the details of the items associated with the PA (qty, cost, etc.)

So assuming you have this then to add items to the PA you would do something like this:

```
  PurchaseAgreement * newPA = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PurchaseAgreement"
                               inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

  newPA.customer = workingPA.customer;
  newPA.attribute1 = workingPA.attribute1;

  for (PAItem *item in workingPA.items) {

     PAItem * newItem = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PAItem"
                               inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
     newItem.purchaseAgreement = savingPA;
     newItem.product = item.product;
     newItem.quantity = item.quantity;
     newItem.cost = item.cost;
     . . .

  }
  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    // Take some action!
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I got to the same point as your answer on my own yesterday, just needed to think it through more clearly. The reason why we have a workingPA is because if a PA comes in with a status of final we don't want the user changing that data, but they might want to use it as a starting point for a new PA, so we make a new PA entity and transfer the data and change its status, so something like this: if (PA status == 4) then workingPA = copy else workingPA = PA...do stuff